# Electron with Angular js 6, dynamic images are not displaying in same build

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I am doing the windows application using Electron JS and Angular v6. I run the cron job where I take the base64 of images and convert into the real image and keep in the assets folder. After this, I am not able to access those images in angular in same build (exe file).

If I take the build again (generate the exe again) which picks the images and are displaying. Anyidea how to display the new images in same exe file.?

Comment: Maybe you should add the images in the assets folder of the compiled app instead of adding them into the projects assets. When building, Angular copy all assets into a different folder in build.

Comment: Let me try, if thst case, that should be added in both place. Isit?

Comment: If my theory is correct, it would be ok to have these images at both places. If this turn out to be wrong, please provide more detailled informations, like your cron job code.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier Actually, when I run the built exe which does not picking up the new images. For example, ignore the cron, simply If I add the new images into the dist/asset/<folder-name> which is not displaying. 

The same If I take the rebuild which picking up the images.